# How to obtain Cross regional deployment using ARMTemplate

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-rm-template

I want to do cross regional deployment using ARM Template.

**Example 1:**
 I have two resource group's A & B. A resource group has one storage account. I want to access A's storage account in B's resource group services.

**Example 2:**
 I have two resource group's A & B. A resource group has one application insight service. I want to access A's application insight in B's ApiApp service with Instrumentation key added in ApiApp "appsettings".

I have tried adding below code snippet in ARMTemplate:

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "nestedTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "testresgrp01",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
              "name": "[parameters('appinsightname')]",
              "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
              "location": "South Central US",
              "properties": {

              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "parameters": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "name": "[parameters('appinsightname')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "location": "South Central US",
      "properties": {

      }
    }
```

But this section errors while deployment giving below error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment :  - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The 
template resource 'nestedTemplate' at line '224' and column '10' is invalid. The api-version '2016-07-01' used to deploy the 
template does not support 'ResourceGroup' property. Please use api-version '2017-05-10' or later to deploy the template.
```

If I remove  **"resourceGroup": "testresgrp01",** section, the resource deployment creates a new service in resourcegroup.

How to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: how are you deploying the template? vsts?

Comment: the error message says `Please use api-version '2017-05-10' or later to deploy the template`, have you tried that?

Comment: @4c74356b41 - I am deploying the ARMTemplate using PowerShell.

Comment: @John Gardner - Yes I have tried using '2017-05-10' api version but same error is thrown always.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your Azure Powershell modules are outdated, update them to the latest and try again.

I usually delete all modules and install from scratch to ensure no conflicts.

Comment: I tried this option also. By uninstalling and re-installing the Azure modules. But then also same error is thrown..for api version

Comment: hello? can you show your code? @Amruta are you deploying with powershell?